# $C_d$ is bigger at laminar or turbulent flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, flow, aerodynamics, turbulence

Bodies can be subjected to pressure drag or friction drag. But let's consider the overall drag coefficient $C_d$.

My question is: **$C_d$ is bigger at laminar or turbulent flow?**

[image: Cd for blunt and streamlined bodies]

This image represents the Cd for both blunt and streamlined bodies.

**Horizontal Flat plate:** My first argument is the velocity gradient is higher on turbulent boundary layer, which is proportional to *Cf*, which is proportional to $C_d$; So $C_d$ must be higher to turbulent BL.

My second argument is I've just done an exercise of a flow on a flat plate, where they asked to calculate the drag on the flat plate considering 2 situations; one where transition occurred, and other considering turbulent from the x=0. The result was higher **drag** to turbulent regime.

So my question is, why in the plot above for a flat plate, shows *Cd* is higher to laminar flow if we have already argued it is higher to turbulent flow?

**Airfoil:** $C_d$ is higher to laminar flow. Why? On an airfoil there are the combination of pressure and friction effects. Drag due to friction must be higher on turbulent flow; Drag due to pressure gradient must be lower on turbulent flow, and higher on laminar regime due to an higher wake. Should we conclude pressure effect dominates on an airfoil, resulting in higher *Cd* on laminar regime? But I think on airfoils friction effect dominates over pressure.

**Blunt bodies:** can we say $C_d$ is higher on laminar part? Pressure effects dominate for sure on blunt bodies, which creates bigger wakes if the flow is laminar, resulting in bigger *Cd* on laminar part and lower $C_d$ on turbulent part.

**Bonus question:** on a blunt body, like the flow around a cylinder. Pressure is high on the frontside of the cylinder, and is low on the wake. So the positive net pressure force shouldn't help it move forward, unlike what happens to golf balls which we want to reduce the pressure differences to make it move further?

Comment: Drag force is lower for laminar flow, but $C_d$ is higher because the denominator in the definition of $C_d$ is smaller for laminar flow (compared to turbulent flow). This only means that, when you go from laminar to turbulent flow regime, the drag force does not grow as rapidly as the "inertial force" whose scale is given by the denominator of $C_d$.

Comment: but D∝$C_d$....

Comment: No it is not. How would you go from laminar to turbulent flow without changing the denominator in the definition of $C_d$?

Comment: so what am I missing if D=1/2 * rho * U^2 * $C_d$ *A ?

Comment: Yes correct. But there is one way in which you can transition from laminar to turbulent flow without changing the denominator of the formula for $C_d$. That would be by decreasing the viscosity of the fluid while keeping everything else fixed. In this case the dimensional drag $D$ indeed reduces as you transition from laminar to turbulent flow.